# Is it possible to increase the size of OpenBSD's bsd.rd without building it from source?

Tags: kernel, openbsd, size, ramdisk

Having a bsd.rd extracted from an installation image and mounted as a vnode I can see there is 0.2MB free space available for additional files such as used during unattended installation.

I want to copy a file 1MB in size but it obviously won't fit.

Having that said, is there any way to increase the size of the ramdisk kernel without building it from source?

My idea was to copy its content to `newcontent.d`, move my additional file into it, run `makefs newcontent.fs newcontent.d` on it, then `rdsetroot bsd.rd.uc newcontent.fs` and finally compress it and put back on an installation media.

Sadly, while the size of original bsd.rd is 3.3MB the copy of it takes 180MB...

I measure the size of directories using `du -hs /path/to/directory`.

Comment: Can't you provide the extra content as a `site71.tgz` file set, as described in [`install.site(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/install.site)?

Comment: @Kusalananda First of all, thanks for the suggestions.
Unfortunately the OpenBSD installation program detects only the internal storage on a chromebook it is suppose to be installed on.
It does not even recognize the USB stick with file sets.
My only hope right now is to make wifi working and install with sets fetched from a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone came up with a similar question some time ago [on the `misc@openbsd.org` mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=164331543922325&w=2).  Quoting directly Stuart Henderson's answer:

> > Hello, I want to build "bigger" bsd.rd image. Does rebuilding it only way
> > to increase it? Can I somehow increase its size and just rdsetroot new
> > disk.fs?
>
> You'll need to build a release(8) after adjusting at least FSSIZE in the
> relevant Makefiles under src/distrib, maybe also MINIROOTSIZE in kernel
> config.

So, apparently not, you can't do it without rebuilding the kernel.